# Tunneling all subdomain request to a local machine

Tags: networking, tunnel, tunneling, http-tunneling, pagekite

I am using [Pagekite](http://pagekite.net/) to tunnel all request from my cloud server to my local machine. My setup is I have this Linode cloud server with Public IP where I installed Pagekite.

I am running this from my localmachine (and works, where *yourdomain.com* points to the cloud server IP):

```
./pagekite.py --clean --frontend=any-subdomain.yourdomain.com:80 
--service_on=http:any-subdomain.yourdomain.com:localhost:8080:examplepassword2
```

However I am not able to "tell" the front-end sever to just forward everything to my local machine like this:

```
./pagekite.py --clean --frontend=*.yourdomain.com:80 
--service_on=http:*.yourdomain.com:localhost:8080:examplepassword2
```

As it throws

```
>>> Hello! This is pagekite.py v1.0.1.200424.                   [CTRL+C = Stop]
    It looks like your Internet connection might be down! Will retry soon.
     - Check whether you can ping pagekite.net or google.com
     - Check whether `*.yourdomain.com` can be looked up in DNS
 << pagekite.py [down]     No kites ready to fly.  Waiting...
```

Anyone have experience with Pagekite and knows how to work-around this?

Comment: I am thinking of a solution with Pagekite, I may just change it's port from 80,443 to 8080,8443 then put an nginx in from of it that will proxy forward to (in the cloud server) sub.yourdomain.com:8080 or sub.yourdomain.com:8443 and one server (my local machine) can pick it up. Since the problem when someone access my server in form of any-sub.yourdomain.com:80 then if there's no local machine running with that kite name the server (pagekite) shows "Sorry! (fe) " the idea is for my server to handle all request from any subdomain, so I am thinking of such approach as a work around

Comment: could you get this configuration to work?